# Start a new git branch with the changes from my last push

Tags: git, github

I have two git branches master and first_puppet. I pushed first puppet up to github and then created a pull request. I have now subsequently started working on a new feature, but mistakenly have been working in the first_puppet branch. I want to move all my changes since I pushed on first_puppet to a new branch. How might I do so? Basically my confusion centers around shouldn't I always be branching from master. And if I don't branch from master will there be any problems. Thank you very much for you your help.
-Tom

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are on the `first_puppet` branch and `origin` points to the remote where you pushed to:

```
git branch new_branch
git reset --hard origin/first_puppet
git checkout new_branch
```

This creates a new branch from the current HEAD, then resets the current branch back to the same ref as you pushed upstream, then switches to the new branch.

The new branch still contains everything in the `first_puppet` branch, plus your new changes (which is not necessarily a problem! it depends how you want to use branches, see below).  If you only want it to contain the new changes you could either create another branch, branched off master, and cherry-pick the new changes:

```
[after running the first steps above]
git checkout -b new2 master
git cherry-pick first_puppet..new_branch
```

**Or** you could rebase the new branch onto master and remove the unwanted commits:

```
[after running the first steps above]
git branch --set-upstream-to=master
git rebase -i
[edit the list of commits to only include the new ones]
```

> Basically my confusion centers around shouldn't I always be branching from master.

Not necessarily. If you want to do another set of changes that are based on the ones in the `first_puppet` branch then it makes sense to branch off that.

If you want to make some independent changes that might form a separate pull request, starting from master might make more sense.

> And if I don't branch from master will there be any problems.

It depends what you consider problems!

You will have a branch that includes two sets of changes. That might be good, or it might be a problem. Fundamentally there is no reason you must always branch from master, but it might make sense for you as a convention or for a particular workflow.